# Using Variable to Multiply Math.random()

Tags: javascript, random

I need to multiply the Math.random() method with a variable. Example:

```
a = 2;
b = Math.floor(Math.random()*a);
alert(b);
```

This however doesn't do anything. Is there a specific way I need to write it? If not then why will the javascript alert if I put alert(b); or something of the like.

Comment: What do you want to do with the random variable.  Unless you're using a repl like within node.js, you have to do something with the variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't do anything*"? The code is valid, but of course you will need some kind of output (`alert`, `console.log`, DOM manipulation, return in repl) to see the results.

Comment: What do you mean about it doesn't do anything?

Comment: The code seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/SdpfK/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 and you are `floor`ing it so multiplying it by 1 wont get you anything but 0 when you `floor()` it.

Comment: Just an example. I have now changed it to 2 since that seems to be confusing people.

Comment: So run it a few times and you will eventually get something other than zero.

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens. It should alert but it does nothing.

Comment: Then you likely have an error elsewhere in your code. This alerts for me just fine http://jsfiddle.net/NSqhJ/

Comment: Well I have removed everything but it and it does nothing, I even removed even it and replaced it with something that would work always but nothing so it just doesn't seem to be calling it.

Comment: Not using a debugger. Which is probably bad... oh well. I apparently had no problem so I will just pick yours as the right answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Um... Multiplying by 1 is a no-op. Try `a=10` and see if you get any better results.

Comment: Well, humour me. Try `a=10` and see if you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, are you doing anything with the result? `alert`? `document.write`?

Comment: It probably won't work with 10 either... Consider some small fraction such as .0293, multiple by 10 = .293. Floor that and you get... ZERO. Try a larger multiplier such as 1000.

Comment: I am alerting it. But nothing happens.

Comment: Any error messages in your console? It's strange for "nothing" to happen. [Try this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pyj2H/) and compare the code to yours. Is anything different?